# android: special file permissions

Tags: android

I have observed some erratic behavior in the android file system. 
The logcat utility reads its data from the following 4 buffers :

```
/dev/log/main
/dev/log/events
/dev/log/radio
/dev/log/system
```

Let's take an example of the radio buffer for which
              User = radio
              Group = log

Now suppose I attempt to read this file as the radio user, or I have my group set as log.... In which case I will be able to read all the data successfully.

But suppose I change my current uid to 'shell' in a manner that I don't belong to group log...

What I observe is that I am still able to read the file successfully... But I am only able to read those entries which have been written by some other process which runs in the context of shell and does not belong to group log.

I understand that if I got have read or write permissions on a file ... If I attempt to access that file I will get a file permission error. But that is not the case here...
looking for some explanation regarding this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Log files have **rw** permissions for all users, but magic happens because they are no regular files. Log files are [device files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file).